# Заполнение ComboBox из БД (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding

Добрый день, есть Класс со свойствами и выборкой:

```
public partial class Register : Window
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Roles> ItemsForRoles { get; set; }

    public Register()
    {
            DbModelContainer db = new DbModelContainer();

            ObservableCollection<Roles> ItemsForRoles = new ObservableCollection<Roles>();

            var query = db.RolesSet.ToList();

            foreach (var roles in query)
            {
            ItemsForRoles.Add(
                new Roles { Id = roles.Id, Name = roles.Name }
                );
            }
    }
}
```

И ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Name="role" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsForRoles}">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Name}"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в XAML коде правильно сделать привязку данных на ComboBox, так что-бы выводились все записи, а не одна. 
Нужно вывести из БД записи в этот ComboBox и передаваемым параметром сделать Id, а не Name.

Решение вопроса из последних комментариев (установка IsEnabled=false первому(выбранному) итему):

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
       <Style.Triggers>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="-1">
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
           </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: А зачем вы задаете отдельно ComboBoxItem если у вас уже есть айтемы в ItemsSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно только свойство `ItemsSource` для вашего `Combobox`

```
<ComboBox Name="role" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsForRoles}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedValuePath="Id"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Id}">
</ComboBox>
```

то что вы отдельно задаете `ComboBoxItem`перетирает ваш список `ItemsSource`

Comment: Ничего не выводит

Comment: Все исправил, нужно было к Loaded окна добавить this.DataContext = this;

Comment: Спасибо. Только он почему-то при выборе начал уже в приложении подсвечивать комбобокс красной рамкой, хотя соседний так не делает :)

Comment: @Дмитрий возможно не видит какой то из параметров DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                  SelectedValuePath="Name"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Id}"

Comment: @Дмитрий Попробую создать тестовый пример и проверить

Comment: SelectedValue="Id" вот так не краснеет

Comment: @Дмитрий не уверен, что понял решена проблема или нет

Comment: Да, решена, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Дмитрий если сделать так SelectedValue="Id", то SelectedValue примет строковое значение для Id. Биндинг же задает привязку к свойству public int Id { get; set; } Очень странно, что у вас видит ItemsForRoles. Но не видит Id. Может получится так SelectedValue="{Binding Id}" или Binding ItemsForRoles.Id

Comment: Нет, так тоже краснеет, с этим я думаю уже разберусь методом тыка. А не подскажите, как мне теперь можно на 1 из Итемов повесить  IsEnabled=false?

Comment: @Дмитрий нужно использовать стили для ComboboxItem, вот тут аналогичный вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003318/how-to-disable-combobox-items

Comment: Решил, может быть кому-то пригодится, в базовом посте добавил в самый низ код.

Comment: И еще момент, в xaml коде чтобы передать SelectedValue достаточно было оставить SelectedValuePath="Id", затем пo role.SelectedValue - выводит Id